# HTML form fields unselectable on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: html, symfony, firefox, twig, forms

I have the following markup in my Symfony 2 application which generates a form using `from_widget` and `form_row`.

```
<tr class="ui-sortable-handle" data-order="45">
    <form novalidate="" action="/administration/guide/9/row/45/update/" method="post"></form>
    <td style="width: 15%;">
        <select id="guide_row_channel" class=" form-control" name="guide_row[channel]">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="1">Belleisle</option>
            <option value="2">Dalmilling</option>
            <option value="3">Seafield</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

My Twig template which is:

```
<tr data-order="{{ row.id }}">
    <form method="post" action="{{ path('guide_row_update', { 'GuideId' : guide.id, 'id' : row.id }) }}" novalidate>
    {{ form_widget(form.channel) }}
    // ... some more form_widget and form_row in here ...                   
        <td align="right" style="width: 110px;">
        // ... button in here ...               
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

I am experiencing an issue where the form fields are unselectable on Firefox, but work perfectly fine in Chrome.

Do I have some blatantly invalid HTML that Chrome is letting fly but Firefox is not? Why does the form auto-close in the markup as it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by jQuery UI configuration.

I have set a class of `sortable` on the table:

```
    <table class="table">
        <tbody class="sortable">
```

Which allocates a `ui-sortable-handle` class on the `<tr>`s (as shown in my original question):

`<tr class="ui-sortable-handle" data-order="45">`

I also have the following jQuery snippet in my code (which, by the way, is [not recommended by jQuery](https://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/))

`$(this, ".draggable").disableSelection();`

Removing this line above solved my issue.

It does seem to be a [Firefox-related problem](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-disableselection-firefox-issue-with-inputs).

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have some blatantly invalid HTML […]?
>
> [from comments] I can see it is self-closing, but that is my question - why is it doing that?

Yes, you have written invalid HTML – you can not have `form` as a child element of `tr` or `table`.

Either the `form` has to be *around* the whole `table` element, or *inside* a `td` (or `th`) element.

Because of your invalid HTML code, the browser tries to auto-correct when it creates the DOM – and although *how* to auto-correct is kind-of specified with HTML5, browsers still tend to do that differently. And since `form` can not have `td` as child element, some browsers might close the `form` before they continue build the DOM tree.

A tip: [Validate](https://validator.w3.org/) your HTML code next time when you face such an issue. The validator will tell you about such invalid nesting of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The form is open and close in the same line:

```
<form novalidate="" action="/administration/guide/9/row/45/update/" method="post"></form>
```

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No. I can see it is self-closing, but that is my question - _why_ is it doing that? In my questions i've included my Twig template where i'm not closing the form immediately. The source is taken directly from Firebug in Firefox.